# How to get Tailwind/React store navigation to dropdown on hover

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

How to I get the dropdown to work on hover - what changes would I need to make in the react implementation for this?

https://tailwindui.com/components/ecommerce/components/store-navigation

I tried adding onmouse events but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: At the moment https://tailwindui.com/components/ecommerce/components/store-navigation only works on click event. I would also like to implement this when I hover the mouse over the menu.

Comment: Your question is a bit too short to fully understand what you're expecting to happen, but maybe this section of the Tailwind docs on how to handle hover state will help? => https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

If you could provide a visual of what you expect to have happen and what you have tried, I think that would be super beneficial.